# Pivot table consisting data from three separate tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-tables

I have three tables with a very similar layout, where i would like a pivot table to present the data in a certain way and i'm wondering if it is possible.
Each table starts with a column for participent name, followed by 3 columns with different data, which i do not need for this pivot. After this follows total column and then a column for each calender month (jan, feb, mar,. Etc. etc.). The three tables are named SalaryHours,SalaryDKK and SalaryPCT

I would like, if possible to present my data the following way

Participant(s):----:Total:Jan 
Participant A:----:----:----: 
--------------:SalaryHours:Value(TotalSalaryHours):Value(JanSalaryHours) 
--------------:SalaryDKK:Value(TotalSalaryDKK):Value(JanSalaryDKK) 
--------------:SalaryPCT:Value(TotalSalaryPCT):Value(JanSalaryPCT)

I have all the data in my datamodel, so it's only the "presentation" form, i'm wondering if possible or if i need to find an alternative.

I hope my request is understandable.

Best regards, Mikki

Comment: You could combine the tables in PowerQuery (Data>From Table/Range) and output as you described.